# Library that simplifies File IO

Tags: java, file-io

What library can I use for file IO? For example, creating a file called "test.txt" and then writing the word "Hello World!" to it.

I want to write clean code like in `Ruby` where I can just say

```
myFile = open(path, permissions, encoding)
myFile.write("Hello world!")
myFile.close
```

Without having to worry about any of this BufferedReader things or InputStreamReader things etc. cluttering my code.

Comment: Not sure if [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from Apache Commons IO might help you. IMO dealing with `BufferedReader` and other related classes is not so painful...

Comment: Guava provide some stuff in `Files`: `Files.write("Hello world!".getBytes(), new File("someFile"));` (not tested)

Comment: You would typically put all the `BufferedReader` stuff in a method. In that way your code will not be cluttered.

Comment: Ever considered using Groovy?

Comment: @RobAu I figured if I'm going to do that I might as well grab a library that does that for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache Commons IO library or the I/O features in Google's Guava.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IOExplained

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Apache Commons and FileUtils class. It has readFileToString and writeStringToFile methods for example and a lot of more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using 3rd Party you can write basic text in relatively few lines:

```
public class SO3 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop", "tester.txt");

    try (RandomAccessFile files = new RandomAccessFile(path.toString(), "rw")){
        Files.write(path, "text & more text".getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The only real clutter is the enforced checked exception.